# Appending to config files with `tee -a`

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to wrap my head around the thinking behind doing say

```
echo "nameserver 10.42.0.1" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

rather than

```
echo "nameserver 10.42.0.1" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

as root (e.g., after `su` or `sudo bash`). Is it a minimize time as root thing or is there something else to it?

Comment: this is not RPi related ... it is a linux question

Comment: Is it really a Linux idiom as opposed to a Pi Linux idiom? The place where (I think) I've encountered it the most is the context of the Pi – but most of my commuting life is spent of BSD systems. My interest it the question is around writing for a Pi audience, personally I'd do it with `vi`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a common Linux idiom. The idea behind it is to run only the `tee` process as root instead of a shell. Since `tee` is very simple, it's much less likely to have bugs or respond to unexpected user input in a dangerous way, compared to e.g. `bash`.